# Right configuration to convert a small and a large number from XML to Json using com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper class

Tags: java, json, xml, scala, jackson-databind

How can I configure the com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper class so that given an xml like:

```
<Person>
    <Age>33</Age>
    <GrantID>815721008160186381772405</GrantID>
</Person>
```

Can turn it into a json string like:

```
{
    "Person": {
     "Age": 33,
     "GrantID": "815721008160186381772405"
     }
}
```

See the detail that 33 can be converted into a number, but 815721008160186381772405 cannot and is converted into a string.

My sample program:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{JsonNode, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper

object Xml2Json extends App {
  val xml: String = "<Person><Age>33</Age><GrantID>815721008160186381772405</GrantID></Person>"
  val xmlMapper: XmlMapper = new XmlMapper()
  val node: JsonNode = xmlMapper.readTree(xml) //.readTree(xml.getBytes())
  val jsonMapper: ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
  val json: String = jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(node)

  println(json)
}
```

Output:

```
{"Age":"33","GrantID":"815721008160186381772405"}
```

Comment: Underscore-java library has static method U.xmlToJson(xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible if you use the [`ObjectWriter.withRootName`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter.html#withRootName-java.lang.String-) method with the constructed `ObjectWriter` writer from your already existing `ObjectMapper` mapper present in your code, so giving the correct rootname (in your case the value *Person*):

```
val node: JsonNode = xmlMapper.readTree(xml)
val jsonMapper: ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
val json: String = jsonMapper.writer()
                             .withRootName("Person")
                             .writeValueAsString(node)
//Output: {"Person":{"Age":"33","GrantID":"815721008160186381772405"}}
println(json)
```